# Are wage loss insurance programs worth the cost compared to having an emergency fund?

Tags: canada, insurance, emergency-fund

Anybody heard of these wage loss insurance programs?

The idea is in my provence short term disability only pays out up to 8 weeks and long term disability does not kick in until 6 months. The idea is you pay $XXX and you will get X% of your wage in that in-between period. (As I understood it)

If I already have a 6 month emergency fund I just figured I would use that but is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a closer look at the fine print in your long-term disability policy (employer-provided?) before taking on a short-term wage insurance program to cover just the 4-month gap.  *Many* long-term disability policies
do not provide enough of a replacement income, and/or they come with all kinds of
reasons why the insured is not eligible to receive payments under the policy.
For example, if you are a professional and are disabled to the point
that you cannot practice your profession but are nonetheless able to do
work of *some* kind, e.g. work as a greeter in a large department store, you may be
told that your policy payments will stop since you *can* work, even though
you thought it meant that you would be paid as long as you cannot practice your profession.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your willingness to absorb the risk. 
This is the nature of most insurance. Your car is worth $20,000? You decide you can absorb the cost of a new car, so you only buy the liability your province requires, but not the coverage to your own car. That's a choice. 
If you have a long-term disability, are you comfortable enough to spend that savings before the coverage starts?

Comment: I think thats my problem... I do not know if I am willing or not?

Comment: A man wiser than I was quoted as saying,"if you choose not to decide, you still have made a choice." You need to look at the value of that 4 month gap, and the annual cost to protect. Disability is far more likely than death, so the expense would probably be much more than 1% of the value, but that depends on age, of course.